# Unable to establish connection using mamp

Tags: apache, ssl, mamp

I followed the tuotorial : http://www.webopius.com/content/355/getting-mamp-working-with-ssl-on-os-x to get ssl certificate. After editing everything, I am getting the following error: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:127.

Please let me know how to resolve this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

juste place the ssl certificate in the firefox certificate session by

firing up the browser and click on:

Edit --> Preferences --> Advances --> Certificates.

from there click on View Certificates and on "Import"

you will get a dialog box where to choice your certificate

and add it in the existing list of ssl certificate.

now you will be able to use your certificate in localhost.

Comment: I tried this and it's not letting me do this. And also, i have not edited my site name etc in <virtualHost> except key and certificate.

Comment: do you mean you are not able to add the certificate in firefox certificate list ?

Comment: No, i could add it. But, it's giving me the same error. And I am getting - The requested URL /myweb/index.html was not found on this server error on chrome when i type in-http://192.168.2.7/myweb/index.html.